# (python) In nested loops, why and how does indenting print() affect the result

Tags: python, nested-loops

Hi  was just playing around and saw that these 2 codes result in two different outcomes. Obviously the outcomes going to be different but why? How do they work differently? Thanks in advance!

1st code

```
number = [5,2,5,2,2]

for x_count in number:

    output = ""

    for count in range(x_count):

        output = output + "x"

    print(output)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxRfc.png)

2nd code

```
number = [5,2,5,2,2]

for x_count in number:

    output = ""

    for count in range(x_count):

        output = output + "x"

        print(output)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rujt2.png)

Comment: In Python, indentation determines scope. So by indenting `print` in the second example, you've made it part of the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `range()` function returns a sequence of numbers, starting from 0 and increments by 1, and stops BEFORE a specified number.

You just need to walk down the loops in steps to figure out what's happening:

#### The First Program

You have a list of integers of 5 and 2. with a total of **5** items.

```py
number = [5,2,5,2,2]
```

In the first outer loop, the x_count variable holds the value of each item in the list

```py
for x_count in number:
```

That means:

- first iteration, `x_count = 5`
- second iteration, `x_count = 2`
- third iteration, `x_count = 5`
  ...and so on

Next, you're creating a variable `output` to hold a string of characters:

```py
output = ""
```

The inner loop is where it gets tricky:

```py
for count in range(x_count):
```

the range function would generate a range of values from zero to `x_count`, remember the value of the `x_count` variable is dependent on the current iteration of the outer loop.
so the range function argument would look like this:

- first outer loop iteration - `range(5)`
- second outer loop iteration - `range(2)`
- third outer loop iteration - `range(5)`
  ...and so on

Within the inner loop, you're concatenating the string "x" to the existing value of `output`. And ONLY WHEN the inner loop is complete, you print the value of `output` (because the print statement is outside the inner loop i.e within the outer loop context).
That means:

- First inner loop iteration, value of `output` is `"xxxxx"` because the inner loop counts up to 5 (`range(x_count) where x_count = 5`)
- Second inner loop iteration, value of `output` is `"xx"` because the inner loop counts up to 2 (`range(x_count) where x_count = 2`)

...and so on.

Printing the value of range outside the inner loop would only give you 5 strings, because the print statement is within the outer loop and the outer loop only counts up to 5 (length of the `number` list).

#### The Second Program

Everything in the first program applies except the context of the print statement. in this case, the `print` statement is within the inner loop context which means it only prints values when an iteration happens within the context of the inner loop.
it will print the value of `output` in this order:

- On first iteration of the outer loop, `x_count = 5` therefore on the first iteration of the inner loop, the print statement will be called 5 times because the loop counts from 0 - 5 (`range(5)`),

  - for each iteration in the inner loop, concatenate a new "x" string to `output`.

Result:

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
```

- On the second iteration of the outer loop, `x_count = 2`, therefore on the second iteration of the inner loop, the print statement will execute 2 times because the loop counts from 0 - 2 (`range(2)`)

  - output is reset back to an empty string
  - for each iteration concatenate "x" to `output`

Result:

```
x
xx
```

> Repeating this flow for the next 3 items in the list. you get:

range(5):

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
```

range(2):

```
x
xx
```

range(2):

```
x
xx
```

Putting it all together when both loops are complete, you have this:
Result:

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
x
xx
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
x
xx
x
xx
```